# android studio fragment onclick cannot access edittext

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, onclicklistener

I have something like:

```
public class EditCustomer extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //this is what runs when you click the button
         EditText editName=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
         System.out.println(editName.getText()); //FAILS

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment4
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_customer, container, false);
    Button a = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.update_cust_btn);
    a.setOnClickListener(this);  //adds button listener
    EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    System.out.print(editText.getText().toString());


    return v;
}
...
```

For some reason, **null pointer exception** in EditText. When I try the same line in my `onCreateView()` in the same fragment, it works just fine. Is there something I'm not getting here?

Comment: can you show your onCreateCiew() ?

Comment: @ArpitPatel just did now

Comment: ya i am tring and send you demo

Comment: are you want edittext value on button click??

Comment: @ArpitPatel yea I want the value, thanks!

Comment: try adding as in your onCreateview() like **editText.getText().toString()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1** import this two package.

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

**Step 2**  implement **OnClickListener** in your class

`public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener`

**Step 3** Define Button and EditText in onCreateView();

**Note :-** Declare Button and EditText Globally

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container,
                false);

        Admin_Email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_admin_email);

        btn_SET = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_SET);
        btn_ChangePassword = (Button) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_ChangePassword);

        btn_SET.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_ChangePassword.setOnClickListener(this);


        return rootView;

    }
```

**Step 4** Outside of the OnCreateView() define the Onclick() Method using Id

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_SET:

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+Admin_Email.getText().toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                break;
            case R.id.btn_ChangePassword:

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

**My Full Code**

```
mport android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;



public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {



    Button btn_SET, btn_ChangePassword;
    static EditText Admin_Email;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container,
                false);

        Admin_Email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_admin_email);

        btn_SET = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_SET);
        btn_ChangePassword = (Button) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_ChangePassword);

        btn_SET.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_ChangePassword.setOnClickListener(this);


        return rootView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_SET:

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+Admin_Email.getText().toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);



                break;
            case R.id.btn_ChangePassword:

//          

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Please mention changes what you have made.

Comment: I am declaring Edittext  outside of the onCreate()

Comment: That you should mention some where in your answer.